# CSS - can't put menu horizontally - inline doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I can't put the menu horizontally anything i would do. What i am doing wrong?
I suppose that the problem is from inline option, but i am not sure.
If anyone can correct my code i would appreciate very much. Thank you.

HTML code

```
<nav>
    <ul>
         <li class = "current-item"> <a href = "index.php"> Home </a> </li>
         <li> <a href = "profile.php"> Profile </a> </li>
         <li> <a href = "contact.php"> Contact </a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS code

```
nav{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: 288px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 25px;
    height:25px;
    z-index: 2;
}

nav > ul > li {   
    font-size:20px;
    color:white;    
    padding:10px 40px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    z-index: 2;
}

 nav > ul > li> a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000000;
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
}

nav > ul >.current-item > a{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 22px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    height: 28px;
    z-index:2;
    text-decoration:none;

}
nav> ul > li:hover> a{

    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 22px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    height: 28px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: You set the width of your `nav` element to `25px` so it can't contain the elements without wrapping. Otherwise everything is OK. https://jsfiddle.net/y3nrkysm/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the width from nav.

```
nav{
position:absolute;
margin-top: 288px;
margin-left: 0px;
height:25px;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: happy to help you.. :)